# URI routing codigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

In route.php i  tried code

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller';

$route["test"] = 'controller/method/49';

$route["author"] = 'controller/method/48';

$route['404_override'] = '';

as per URI Routing document
```

[document](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

```
 But still url is showing www.example.com/controller/method/48 is not routing
```

i dont know where i am missing,

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood how re route works in CI. If you access `www.example.com/test` if will go to your `controller/method/49` but it will display in your address bar as ``www.example.com/test``

Comment: see @DrixsonOseña commit, did you try `www.example.com/test`, `www.example.com/author` urls, routing does not change url in code, it is allowing new uri to target your default url (controller/method/params) url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route if your url had a id number at end

**Example 1**

`www.example.com/controller/method/48`

If Just have numbers as id you could replace `(:any)` with `(:num)`

`$route["controller/method/(:any)"] = 'controller/method/$1';`

**Example 2**

`www.example.com/test/48`

If Just have numbers as id you could replace `(:any)` with `(:num)`

```
$route["test"] = 'controller/index/$1';
$route["test/update/(:any)"] = 'controller/update/$1';
$route["test/add"] = 'controller/add';
```

and

```
$route["test1"] = 'controller1/index/$1';
$route["test1/update/(:any)"] = 'controller1/update/$1';
$route["test1/add"] = 'controller1/add';
```

And so on.

Comment: Hi mustang, but i have to create $route["test/(:any)"] = 'controller/method/$1';             $route["test1/(:any)"] = 'controller/method/$1'; for seo purpose. Need different name will display in url (test, test1,test2)

Comment: See changes above is that what you mean.